# Ruby on Rails 6: Using many-to-many associations on views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Post model and a Category model. A post can have many categories, and a category can be used on many posts.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author

  has_many :blogs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :category, through: :blogs

  has_rich_text :content
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, through: :blogs
end
```

I have built the schema tables properly. My question is, how do I build a list of posts that contain a category? Ie,

Category: Food

- Post#3
- Post#6

and so

Answer (score 1):

Normally, for the `has_many_and_belongs_to` association

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

this will work...

```
category = Category.first
category.posts.build({title: 'post_1', content: '...'}, {title: 'post_2', content: '...'})
```

For this case,
`has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, through: :blogs`,

you can build category to have many posts through blogs,

`category.blogs.build({title: 'blog_1', post_id: 3}, {title: 'blog_2', post_id: 6})`,

Now, `category` will have `post_3` and `post_6` when saved.

```
category.posts

output: [post_3, post_6]
```